# asp mvc http get action with object as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I got action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateAdmin(object routeValues = null)
{
    //some code
    return View();
}
```

And http post:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateAdmin(
    string email, 
    string nameF, 
    string nameL, 
    string nameM)
 {
        if (email == "" || nameF == "" || nameL == "" || nameM == "")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CreateAdmin", new
            {
                error = true,
                email = email,
                nameF = nameF,
                nameL = nameL,
                nameM = nameM,
            });
  }
```

variable routeValues in `http get Action` is always empty. How correctly pass object as parameter to `[http get] Action`?

Comment: Parameters to get can be passed from URL in form of a querystring. What are you expecting in routeValues for GET?

Comment: is writing a small class containing that parameters not an option?

something like
class CreateAdminModel{string email;string nameF;...}

Comment: CreateAdmin?error=True&email=admin1234%40mail.ru&nameL=asf&nameM=adf
I expecting, that Asp MVC collect parameters from url to routeValues object

Comment: I don't think thats what asp.net MVC do. You can access querystring parameters using `Request.Querystring` collection though.

Comment: You are probably confused because of routeValues parameter of RedirectToAction. But it does not work that way. Since you are passing an anonymous object, you can not even access the properties of routeValues in your HttpGet action. One thing you can do is specify the parameters at the HttpGet action method like

`[HttpGet]

public ActionResult CreateAdmin(bool? error, string email, string nameF, string nameL, string nameM)`

then the querystring values will be mapped to this variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot pass an object to GET, instead try passing individual values like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateAdmin(int value1, string value2, string value3)
{
    //some code
    var obj = new MyObject {property1 = value1; propety2 = value2; property3 = value3};
    return View();
}
```

You can then pass values from anywhere of your app like:

```
http://someurl.com/CreateAdmin?valu1=1&value2="hello"&value3="world"
```

Comment: There is another way which is explained where: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1480429/3090593
Send parameters as JSON object and deserilize it within  A "Custom Filter"

Answer (score 6):

As previously mentioned, you cannot pass an entire object to an HTTPGET Action. However, what I like to do when I do not want to have an Action with hundreds of parameters, is:

- Create a class that will encapsulate all the required parameters
- Pass a string value to my HTTPGET action
- Convert the string parameter to the actual object that my GET action is using.

Thus, say you have this class representing all your input fields:

```
    public class AdminContract
    {
      public string email {get;set;}
      public string nameF {get;set;}
      public string nameL {get;set;}
      public string nameM {get;set;}
    }
```

You can then add a GET Action that will expect only one, string parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAdmin(string jsonData)
{
  //Convert your string parameter into your complext object
  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdminContract>(jsonData);

    //And now do whatever you want with the object
    var mail = model.email;
    var fullname = model.nameL + " " + model.nameF;

    // .. etc. etc. 

    return Json(fullname, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And tada! Just by stringifying and object (on the front end) and then converting it (in the back end) you can still enjoy the benefits of the HTTPGET request while passing an entire object in the request instead of using tens of parameters.

Comment: Good answer except you omitted How the Client (JavaScript) should encode the data and send it to the Action Method.  So you only really provided half an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to a Http Get method like

```
Html.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new {para1=value, para2 = value});
```

and you can have your action defined in the controller like

```
[HtttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionName(Para1Type para1, Para2Type para2)
{
}
```

Comment: You can pass the whole values in a object by having a model and passing a model object.