# pass multiple values/parameters from view to mvc controller shorter way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im new to MVC.. and started to grasp it. I am wondering whether there's a shorter way to pass parameters from view to mvc controller. I am creating a search box with possible conditions.

here's the sample code in the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by fname: @Html.TextBox("fname", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <br/>
        Find by lname: @Html.TextBox("lname", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <br/>
        By Area Code : @Html.TextBox("AreaCode")
        <br/>
        @Html.DropDownList("StateCD", new SelectList(ViewBag.State))
        <br/>
        <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </p>
}
```

in my controller

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Action(string id, string sortorder, string statecd,int? page,string country,string areacode,string city,string zip,string z)
    {
```

}

is there a way to shorten that parameter like as an object or concatenated values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558025/asp-mvc-http-get-action-with-object-as-parameter etc. try searching around more

Comment: Create a View Model and use it to pass data as parameter to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class to represent your search filter and use that as the action method parameter type.

```
public class SearchVm
{
  public strng StateCd { set;get;}
  public string AreaCode { set;get;}
  public string Zip { set;get;}
  // Add other needed properties as well
}
```

and use that as the param

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(SearchVm model)
{
    // check model.AreaCode value etc..
    // to do : Return something
}
```

When the form is submitted Default Model binder will be able to map the posted form data to properties of the method parameter object, **assuming your form field name's match with the class property names**