# Pass array javascript as param to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

firstly sorry for my bad english, my problem is, i have  a controller that receive a list of object as param, but when i try sent this list to controller  always receive null.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(List<class> object)
    {

        //do stuff
    }
```

my javascript

```html
var array= []

array.push()...
document.location = '/MyAction/Controller?object'JSON.stringify(array)

my controller always receive null
```

i alreay tried use ajax, but for some reason ajax call my controler twice, in first call i recieve my list correctly, but in second receive null

```html
       
       var array =[]
       array.push()//just example
       
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            tradicional:true,
            async:true,
            url: '/controller/MyAction',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'object': array}),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                //if succes then load my View passing array as param
                document.location = '/controller/MyAction?object' + JSON.stringify(array) ;

            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i alreay tried use ajax, but for some reason ajax call my controler
>   twice

I'm guessing the first call is a POST request done by the lines:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
```

and the second call is a GET request done by the line:

```
  //if succes then load my View passing array as param
  document.location = '/controller/MyAction?object' + JSON.stringify(array) ;
```

Check if this is the case in the "network" tab of your browser's debugger, decide whether you want to use POST or GET, and configure your controller accordingly. This thread may be helpful: [asp mvc http get action with object as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558025/asp-mvc-http-get-action-with-object-as-parameter)

Comment: if i not add this: //if succes then load my View passing array as param
  document.location = '/controller/MyAction?object' + JSON.stringify(array) ;
After sent to controller the view not load

Comment: If does load, it's in the "response" param of the "success" function. It does not display, though. Can you do "console.log(response)" in the success handler?