# ASP.NET MVC Action Argument Dictionary Removing Elements with @ in them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a controller action with a Dictionary argument:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(Dictionary<string, string> EnteredValues)
```

When I try to invoke this method using JSON, the dictionary entries with an @ sign in them get removed from the list. For instance, if I invoke the method using this JSON:

```
{
    "EnteredValues": {
        "__EVENTTARGET": "",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__LASTFOCUS": "",
        "ctl00$txtContractQuickSearch": "Contract Search",
        "ctl00$txtAdvisorQuickSearch": "Rep Search",
        "New Business.@StartDate": "1/1/2013",
        "New Business.@EndDate": "10/25/2013",
        "New Business.@RegionCode": "All",
        "ShowChart": "on",
        "txtSearchContractNumber": "Contract Number",
        "txtSearchContractFirstName": "Owner First Name",
        "txtSearchContractLastName": "Owner Last Name",
        "DXScript": "1_42"
    }
}
```

The 3 "New Business" entries get removed because they have an @ sign in them. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you insert an additional @ like `"New Business.@@StartDate"` in front of the affected names? That should should escape the string from the Razor syntax.

Comment: I'm not using razor to render anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your dictionary entries with an @ sign with single quotes.

```
"'New Business.@StartDate'": "1/1/2013"
```

Or

```
"New Business.'@StartDate'": "1/1/2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into [model binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474896/in-asp-net-mvc-deserialize-json-prior-to-or-in-controllers-action-method) and [dynamic JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/3806407#3806407), I was able to work around this issue by creating my own Dictionary model binder:

```
public class DictionaryStringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> model = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string contentType = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;

        if (contentType != null && contentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            string content = new StreamReader(controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            var dynamicContent = Json.Decode(content);
            foreach (string property in dynamicContent.GetDynamicMemberNames())
            {
                if (property == bindingContext.ModelName)
                {
                    foreach (string dictionaryProperty in dynamicContent[property].GetDynamicMemberNames())
                    {
                        model.Add(dictionaryProperty, dynamicContent[property][dictionaryProperty]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            model = (Dictionary<string, string>)ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Then inside Globals.asax:Application_Start, I bound this model binder like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(Dictionary<string, string>)] = new DictionaryStringModelBinder();
```

My dictionaries are now property being deserialized even if the key has an @ in it. Note that this will only work if the dictionary is in the root of both the action arguments (i.e. not inside a class within an action argument) and the JSON.